# Is there an idiom for adding a trailing slash to a file path?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a program that takes a folder path as a command line argument. And then I concatenate that with filenames to access those files.

For example, folder_path is "./config/"
and then file_path would be "./config/app.conf" as shown below

```
stringstream ss;
ss << folder_path << "app.conf";
file_path = ss.str();
```

But this wouldn't work if folder_path doesn't contain an ending slash. It seems like a common issue, so I was wondering if there's an idiom for adding the slash at the end if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't know any idiom, but I think that use a library like boost filesystem is much more flexible, you don't have to worry about slashes or backslashes (Windows). Further this library will be part of the standard library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually do this, if the path is in an std::string named pathname:

```
if (!pathname.empty() && *pathname.rbegin() != '/')
    pathname += '/';
```

Or, with basic_string::back():

```
if (!pathname.empty() && pathname.back() != '/')
    pathname += '/';
```

Add a case for backslash if necessary.

Added: Also note that *nix will handle consecutive slashes in path names as a single slash. So in many situations, it's sufficient to just always add a slash without checking.

Answer (score 2):

Linux wont care if you have an extra slash, so /home/user/hello and /home/user//hello are the same location. You could add the slash as a failsafe. Or, you could check for it, by checking the last character.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++14/C++17 [`std::filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem):

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> // C++14.
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // C++14.
//#include <filesystem> // C++17.
//namespace fs = std::filesystem; // C++17.

void addTrailingDelimiter(fs::path& path) {
    if (!path.empty() && path.generic_string().back() != '/')
        path += '/';
}
```

Heed the `fs::path::generic_string()`. That way you do not have to check for [native path delimiters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/format) (WinAPI native != generic, while Posix native = generic).

You might omit `if (path.generic_string().back() != '/')` since Posix and WinAPI don't care about several successive path delimiters.